# VB.NET BalloonTip from different threads

Tags: vb.net

My application runs a GUI thread and a timer-induced worker thread (the worker thread is created implicitly by the `Elapsed` method of the timer).

Some messages are displayed via a BallonTip and the the problem is that tray icons evoked by the BalloonTips do not disappear. I noticed that the number of copies on my icon in the tray is linked to the number of threads that show BallonTip. My code is

```
Public Sub showPopup(xStrMessage As String)
        Me.notifyIcon.Visible = True
        Me.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "VdtServer", xStrMessage, ToolTipIcon.Info)
End Sub
```

How can I solve this? I would naturally like to have a single icon in the tray. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Accidentally answered in an unrelated question (by Hans Passant) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624631/invokerequired-returns-false-despite-call-is-not-from-mainthread)