# InvokeRequired returns False despite call is not from MainThread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, delegates

In VB.Net, I have a form with a checkbox on it - if checked, I want messages to appear as popups, if unchecked messages are to be suppressed.

```
Partial Class mainForm

   ...

Public Delegate Sub dlgShowPopup(xString As String)
Public Sub showPopup(xStrMessage As String)
    If (Me.InvokeRequired) Then
        Dim xDlg As New dlgShowPopup(AddressOf showPopup)
        Me.Invoke(xDlg, xStrMessage)
    Else
        If (Me.cbShowPopup.Checked() = True) Then
            Me.notifyIcon.Visible = True
            Me.notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "VdtServer", xStrMessage, ToolTipIcon.Info)
        End if 
    End If
End Sub

   ...

End Class
```

Problem is `Me.cbShowPopup.Checked()` returns true even in case it is not checked. During investigations, I found out that the `Me.InvokeRequired` never returns false, even when the calling thread is not the MainThread, but WorkerThread. So far, I thought that the main form lives in the MainThread and when called from a different thread, Me.InvokeRequired should fire true.

Comment: Clearly your "Me" reference is wrong.  A very, very common problem in VB.NET, induced by using a type as though it is an object reference.  Like mainForm.showPopup("oops").  That creates a *new* instance of mainForm when you call the method on a worker thread.  You can't see it, the Show() method wasn't called.  And Me.InvokeRequired returns False.

Answer (score 0):

`Me.cbShowPop.Checked` is independent of the Invoke, so I can't really understand how it can return true when it is not checked, unless you have multiple forms of the same type being created.

Your code can be simplified without the need for the explicit delegate like this:

```
Private Sub showPopup(xString As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New Action(Of String)(AddressOf showPopup), xString)
    Else
        If Me.cbShowPopup.Checked Then
            Me.NotifyIcon1.Visible = True
            Me.NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1000, "VdtServer", xString, ToolTipIcon.Info)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also note it is not considered good practise to name a control the same name as its class i.e. you shouldn't call a `NotifyIcon` control `notifyIcon`

Comment: Matt, thanks for the abbreviated notation, it is nice. As for the syntax, I believe it is correct - at least in all other uses of delegates it works correctly the way I posted it. The second code fragment of yours produces a "showPopup is not a type" error.

Comment: What version of the .NET framework are you targeting?